# What does "Ensemble average for a given window of pixels" mean?

Tags: radar, synthetic-aperture-radar

Can someone please let me know what does "ensemble average for a given window of pixels" mean when calculating a coherency or covariance matrix? I have taken this sentence from a paper "Polarimetric Target Decompositions and Light Gradient Boosting Machine for Crop Classification: A Comparative Evaluation".

According to my understanding I have to consider a window of size m x n and take the pixels of a radar image in that window and then perform ensemble averaging i.e. mean of those pixels. Please let me know whether my understanding is correct or not.

As of now I am performing a 2D convolution with a square window and varying their size to analyse the performance.

Here is the document that I am referring to: [Polarimetric Target Decompositions and Light Gradient Boosting Machine for Crop Classification: A Comparative Evaluation](https://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/8/2/97)

Comment: Please provide a link to the document you are quoting

Comment: @Vince, I have added the document to the post.

Answer (score 1):

It's spatial averaging (i.e. multi-looking) from scattering matrix to covariance/coherence matrix.

See this paper for better understanding. [Composite Kernel Method for PolSAR Image Classification Based on Polarimetric-Spatial Information](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/7/6/612)